# Cucumber/Gherkin Step Definitions not linking to feature after updating to IntelliJ 2017

Tags: intellij-idea, cucumber, gherkin

I have recently upgraded IntelliJ to v2017, and now none of my features will link to their step definitions.

The features still run fine, but everything is highlighted in yellow and I am not able to click through to see what step def is linked to what. When hovering over, the message appears: "Undefined step reference"

All plugins have been updated, however the gherkin plugin is running on Version: 163.7743.44

**Is this a case of waiting for an update to gherkin or is there something I can do?**

Comment: Please [file a bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA) with the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Thank you for your help. After hours of trying to find a solution I uninstalled 2017 and installed an older version. Not really a solution, but needs must...

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me few times. I had a maven project imported in IntelliJ.
I just had to open 'maven projects tool window' and click on Re-Import button in order to fix this error. worst case, close the project and re-import.